# Check the array for the same elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array:

```
var objects = [
    {product:'123', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'123', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'12', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'1234', options:{cap:'123', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'1234', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}}
];
```

I need to filter this array in this way:

```
(product === product && options !== options) || (product !== product && options == options)
```

It means that the array should looks like:

```
var objects = [
    {product:'123', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'1234', options:{cap:'123', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'12', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
    {product:'1234', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}}
];
```

Comment: You don't need lodash, you basically have everything you need already https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You can't compare 2 different `options` objects that way

Comment: If it's a duplicate do you want the count to increment or just get rid of the duplicate?

Comment: @Matt answer to that is pretty clear in expected results

Comment: @charlietfl suing because hot coffee is hot is pretty clear too but it happens. More so when you are just using copy and paste. So I don't think it's too far off of a question.

Comment: Can you explain the way you want to filter with your own words? The provided condition makes no sense.

Comment: @Matt the second one

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: if options are equal to each other and products are not equal  - its good  
if options are equal and products are equal too - bad don't pass

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not so efficient but simple) approach

```
objects.map((s)=> JSON.stringify(s)).filter( (s,i,a)=> a.indexOf(s,i+1) == -1 ).map((s)=> JSON.parse(s));
```

**Demo**

```js
var objects = [
{product:'123', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
{product:'123', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
{product:'12', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}},
{product:'1234', options:{cap:'123', fort:'', count:1}},
{product:'1234', options:{cap:'', fort:'', count:1}}
];

objects = objects.map((s)=> JSON.stringify(s)).filter( (s,i,a)=> a.indexOf(s,i+1) == -1 ).map((s)=> JSON.parse(s));

console.log( objects );
```

Explanation

- Convert all items to their string version using `JSON.stringify`
- Remove duplicates
- Parse them back to Objects

**Note**
This answer won't work **if your objects' keys are not in same order** and any `function` values in the object will be removed after `stringify` and `parse`.

Comment: Note, JSON.stringify + JSON.parse will remove any function in object

Comment: Be careful using this approach. If object keys are in different order won't compare properly when stringified

Comment: Yes, agree to both the comments above.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are in different order
I receive an array from client side then concat it with array from db
and then I need to filter result

Comment: @ValeriiMonakhov In that case use deepCompare from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/1984039 for comparison instead of its stringified version.